# Finding all path with specific edge types in Tinkerpop 3

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I want to find all path available with "friend" edge:

```
g.v(1).out("friend").out("friend").....
```

so the result will be all paths from v(1) which can be connected by this edge type. it would be great if I also can limit the search length and can have multiple edge type instead of "friend", something like:

```
g.v(1).out("friend" or "enemy").out("friend" or "enemy). .....
```

what would be gremlin way if I have two nodes and want to find all path/shortest path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jump` to recursively traverse down a path and the `path` step to realize the path traversed:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createClassic()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V(1).as('x').out('knows').jump('x'){it.loops<3}{true}
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V(1).as('x').out().jump('x'){it.get().id() != 5 && it.loops < 6}.path()
==>[v[1], v[4], v[5]]
```

See more details in GremlinDocs:

- http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#jump-step

Comment: thanks for answer but my question was finding:
g.v(1).out("friend" or "enemy").out("friend" or "enemy). ...
so recursively finding all possible path form g.v(1).out('knows').out('knows'). ....
it would be great if I can put a limit for it.

my second question was given two node find all possible paths between them.

Comment: updated my answer to reflect your clarification on the question

Comment: Is this Tinkerpop3 way? (I thought there is no more loop in Tnkerpop3 ?)

Comment: updated answer to TP3 - sorry missed that in the subject of your question.

Comment: I can't understand .loops, I don't know how many step I want to take, I just want to take as many step as I find a "knows", when I don't use loops it won't work

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to not have some ceiling on the number of loops as your result might never return.  Use an arbitrarily large number of loops if you don't want to be overly limited and if you know you will get back some result.  In the end, that closure is just a predicate, so perhaps you could find some other method to allow it to continue to process.  I mean, that's the reason it won't work if you remove the `it.loops` because the predicate will immediately return `true` because `id~=5`...so find some other way to have that closure return false that is more to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
g.V(1).as('x').out('knows').loop('x'){it.loops<100}{true}
```

meaning go from Vertex 1 out via a 'knows' edge and keep doing this until you have done it for 100 times. Needles to say it will return a list of vertices which are connected this way.